# SQL Server partition table performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, database-partitioning

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I have yearly customer data from 2000 to 2010, and from 2000 to 2009, I only need to read, and in the year of 2010, I need both read and write.

So, this requirement and usage scenario makes me think of using SQL Server partition table. But I am not sure whether partition table performance is better than just using one table (of the same schema) for each year? I am wondering whether using light weighted solution (i.e. home made one table for each year) is of better performance compared to using partition table.

BTW: in each year, there is about 100k rows. I only have one hard disk drive. I am also wondering the differences between partition table and partition view.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO NO NO**, very seldomly is a home made brew better than a tested/trusted solution.

Dont reinvent the wheel, use table partitions if you must.

Can you just imagine the *simple* home made solution to `INSERTS/UPDATES/SELECT` and you have to remember to create a new table on the 31 Dec each year, and what if you get hit by a bus, or over sleep, or just plain forget?

Dont do, just D.O.N.T. do it.

Comment: How big is this table, how many records *MILLIONS, BILLIONS,* **GAZILLIONS**?

Comment: Why using partition table is of better performance than using multiple same schema tables?

Comment: "How big is this table, how many records MILLIONS, BILLIONS, GAZILLIONS?" -- 100k record each year. Record I mean row. The disk footprint is about 10G.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, question answered.

Answer (score 2):

You have a 100k rows per year? Simply isn't worth it sorry. And I **would not** roll your own solution either.

Especially with one disk drive which is a far bigger worry...

Comment: Thanks gbn. I am confused about your reply, do you mean using home made solution is better or using partition table is better? And why?